# NHibernate 3.1 Query equals

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, equals

I just updated from NHibernate 2.1 to NHibernate 3.1. I found out that the equals operator for the use of Linq was not implemented for other types then string.
I found an [article](http://www.primordialcode.com/blog/post/nhibernate-3-extending-linq-provider-fix-notsupportedexception) on the internet to solve this problem. This works fine for the basic types but now I want to compare a custom entities and I can't get it to work.

I tried some implementations but none work:

```
ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<CustomEntity>(x => x.Equals(<CustomEntity>(0)))  
ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition<CustomEntity>(x => x.Equals(typeof(CustomEntity))
```

The query I want to execute is as follows:

```
Session.Query<SomeEntity>().Where(x => x.CustomEntity.Equals(CustomEntity);
```

How can I extend the equals to allow this and not get an NotSupportedException?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you cannot or do not want to compare the IDs of CustomEntity?

Comment: I have run into the same issue when building a generic base repository.  Previously I would have an interface which defined the Id property of my models and then do something along the lines of 

x => x.Id.Equals(default(IdType)) where the IdType was a generic type

Answer (score 3):

.Equals method cannot be translated to SQL which is done by the system when you execute Query<>() method. Try using equation like this:

```
Session.Query<SomeEntity>().Where(x => x.CustomEntity.Id == CustomEntity.Id);
```